# Bible.xml script to valid sql insert script

Tags: sql, xml

I have a document, bible.xml, it has all the chapters/verse/books in xml format and I am wondering if anyone had a script that could take the xml tags and create a sql statement with it so that I may place it into the database?

I am looking for a NKJV bible sql insert for my bible site. If anyone has that script that would be even better or anywhere that I could find! I have searched for hours on google with nothing.

EDIT: RDBMS: Mysql

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? What does the XML look like? What is the structure of the tables you want to insert into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the most popular databases have ways to import xml data directly into the scheme.

MS SQL Server - [Examples of Bulk Importing and Exporting XML Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx)

MySQL - [Importing XML and XML Data](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing)

Good luck, and hope this helps some.